# Criar e/ou editar imagem com PHP

Tags: php, imagem

É possível editar imagens com PHP?

Por exemplo, colocar marcas d'água, ou até mesmo fazer um "paint" (com outras linguagens juntas tbm, sem ser só PHP).

OBS: gostaria de uma solução sem uso de *frameworks*.

Comment: Pesquise por [PHP GD](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=gd+php) e [PHP ImageMagick](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=imagemagick+php) para mais exemplos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

Há funções que recortam e redimensionam imagens:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecrop.php
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecopyresized.php

Mas para tarefas mais específicas, há a biblioteca GD:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.image.php

Veja o exemplo da aplicação de marca d`água em uma imagem com GD: http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php

Instalação do GD no seu PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

> O PHP não está limitado a criar apenas saída em HTML. Ele também pode
>   ser usado para criar e manipular arquivos de imagem em uma diversidade
>   de formatos, incluindo gif, png, jpg, wbmp, e xpm. E ainda mais
>   convenietemente, o PHP pode enviar streams de saída de imagem
>   diretamente para o browser. Você precisará compilar o PHP com a
>   biblioteca GD de imagens de funções para isto funcionar. O PHP e GD
>   também podem requerer outras bibliotecas, dependendo dos formatos de
>   imagens com os quais você queira trabalhar.
>   ([Manual do PHP em PT-BR](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.image.php))

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Vlw, realmente é oque precisava

Comment: Por favor, marque a resposta como "aceita", @MatheusLopesMarques

Comment: opa, esqueci :P colocado